# Component is opening in custom navbar built on material UI in react.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have created custom navbar in react using material ui and now I am using react router dom for routing but when Link is clicked this happens

[image]

[image]

My code is below:

```
    <Grid container direction="row" justify="space-evenly" alignItems="center">
    <Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="#How">How It Works</Button></Grid>
    <Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="#Contact">Contact-Us</Button></Grid>
    <Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="#Home">Home</Button></Grid>
    <Router>
    <Link to="/signin"><Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="/signin">Sign-in</Button></Grid></Link>
    <Switch>
        <Route component={Signin} path="/signin"/>
        <Route component={Signup} path="/signup"/>
    </Switch>
    </Router>
    <Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="#">Sign-up</Button></Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Which is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I want it to navigate to other page completely.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you haven't put the other codes (I mean those images and etc.) inside of the router.

you have to put them into the router and set a path with value "/"  to it

your code should look like this:

```
 <Grid container direction="row" justify="space-evenly" alignItems="center">
    <Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="#How">How It Works</Button></Grid>
    <Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="#Contact">Contact-Us</Button></Grid>
    <Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="#Home">Home</Button></Grid>
    <Router>
    <Link to="/signin"><Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="/signin">Sign-in</Button></Grid></Link>
    <Switch>
        <Route component={Signin} path="/signin"/>
        <Route component={Signup} path="/signup"/>
        {/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/}
        {/* I added line below in to your code */}

        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />

        {/* and you have to save all the other parts like those images, etc
           in the HomePage Component and render it in just '/' route.
         */}
        {/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/}
    </Switch>
    </Router>
    <Grid className="pt-4 navlink"><Button  className="navlink" href="#">Sign-up</Button></Grid>
  </Grid>
```